# How can I change Haskell version?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I have two haskell versions downloaded. 8.6.5 and 8.2.2. 
The last thing I did was running stack upgrade in the cmd. But I don't know how to change from one version to the other.

PD: I'm using Windows

Comment: How do you normally run GHC?

Answer (score 1):

if you're using `stack`, the lts gives you the compiler version. For example `lts 14.9` is compiler version `8.6.5` (correspondeces in [official](http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/) webpage).

What's important to remember is that when executed outside a project folder, stack picks up the global configuration (typically at `~/.stack/global-project/stack.yaml`). The confusion comes from the fact that global configuration may have a different `lts` than project configuration. In such case stack will download both version and use each depending on the enviroment it is executed (global or project).

As a recommendation, pick up a `lts` and use it in your global config **and** project config so you'll avoid stack downloading many different versions of haskell compiler.